# Problems with extending the polls application

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I added an additional Model to the polls application (see django tutorial) which is intended to be a parent for a set of questions:

```
models.py
class Section(models.Model):
    section_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    section_description = models.TextField(blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.section_text

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.section_text)
        super(Section, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Question(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text
```

This works fine in the admin. Each question is linked to one section.

Displaying the sections is no problem either:

```
views.py
class UmfrageView(ListView):
    model = Section
    context_object_name = 'latest_section_list'
    template_name = 'umfrage.html'
```

But if I want to pass a section via slug to DetailView it doesn't work (if I use generic.ListView instead, it displays questions from all sections):

```
urls.py
url(
    regex=r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    view=DetailView.as_view(),
    name='detail'
),

views.py
class DetailView(ListView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    template_name = 'detail.html'

detail.html
{% if latest_question_list%}
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <p>{{ question.question_text }}</p>
        {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
        <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

If I use generic.DetailView

```
class DetailView(DetailView):
    [...]
```

the following error shows up:

"Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field. Choices are: choice, id, pub_date, question_text, section"

How do I get the set of questions from one particular section and still have an human-friendly URL via slug?

Thanks!

(If further code is required, I'm more than happy to update)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not use the title of your question to tag it; use the tagging system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DetailView` add method `get_queryset()` to return only required objects as below

```
class DetailView(ListView):
    model = Question
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug') or kwargs.get('slug')
        if slug:
           return Question.objects.filter(section__slug=slug)
        else:
           return Question.objects.all()
```

Comment: You can simply `return Question.objects.filter(section__slug=slug) or Question.objects.all()`

Comment: This works perfect: return Question.objects.filter(section__slug=slug).order_by('pub_date')